# rsync from remote generates error `Name or service not known`

Tags: ssh, rsync

Context:
I've configured my `~/.ssh/config` so I can use a shorthand for sshing into the remote. Therefore, this works;-

```
ssh somename
```

But..

If I use the same name when trying to rsync from the remote with this

```
rsync -avz --exclude 'log' --max-size=5m somename:/home/remote-user/copy-from-dir/ /home/local-user/copy-to-dir
```

Then I get this error;-

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname /home/local-user/copy-to-dir: Name or service not known
bash: --server: command not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(601) [Receiver=3.0.8]
```

I'm not using the `user@remote` form because I'm connecting via a non-default key, so I have to configure `.ssh/config`.

Why is ssh attempting to connect to the local path? And what is the correct form to use for this case?

Comment: Please try `rsync -vvv --dry-run somename:/home/remote-user/copy-from-dir/ /home/local-user/copy-to-dir`. Although it will copy nothing (`--dry-run` with no `-a`) it will show you how it's trying to connect to the remote, and what command it thinks it's running.